# Workaround for starting zabbix agent on Ubuntu. update-rc.d LSB mismatch

Tags: ubuntu, boot, zabbix, lsb, update

I am trying to run the zabbix-agent (1.8.1) on boot on Ubuntu (lucid 10.04).

Zabbix is installed just fine, and it manually starts just fine with `/etc/init.d/zabbix-agent start`

However it doesn't start on boot, because when I run:

sudo update-rc.d zabbix-agent default

I get:

```
update-rc.d: warning: zabbix-agent start runlevel arguments (none) do not match LSB Default-Start values (2 3 4 5)
update-rc.d: warning: zabbix-agent stop runlevel arguments (none) do not match LSB Default-Stop values (0 1 6)
```

After googling around I found some cryptic information about this being a possible bug with Zabbix's startup scripts, but I can't find a workaround. I'm trying to understand how the update-rc.d system works, but I'm not getting very far.

How can I modify this setup to start the zabbix-agent on startup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you also add the server to start at boot?

sudo chmod 755 /etc/init.d/zabbix-server
sudo update-rc.d zabbix-server defaults

sudo chmod 755 /etc/init.d/zabbix-agent
sudo update-rc.d zabbix-agent defaults

Comment: I did chmod the zabbix-agent script. I am not running the server on this machine. I am only running the agent.

Comment: maybe its just a fat finger, use defaults instead of default

Comment: Hey hey, lookie there. I did have a typo. Now I've got another problem, because the command executes correctly now, but it does not start zabbix. Hrm, I guess I'll go look elsewhere for the problem. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I realized that I had another problem with my Zabbix config. file that was causing a fail on startup. I appreciate you helping me isolate the issue.